# Azure Pipelines/Dataflow fails when ingesting an empty JSON from API

Tags: azure, etl, azure-synapse

Table in our dwh has NOT NULL constraints. So whenever an empty JSON arrives from our API call, the dataflow fails because "it cannot insert NULL values in NOT NULL constraint columns".

The empty JSON files which we get about once per week, is just an empty array.

What is the best/simplest way to handle this issue?

The main thing I want to fix is that the pipelines doesnt fail. I dont want to read it into the dwh or anything like that. Nor do I neccessarily need to log it.

Any help Would be really appreciated

Have tried adding some filter in dataflow and the pipeline but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use assert transformation to achieve your requirement. Assert filter out the null columns as mentioned below:

Add assert transformation to source add description as you required and use `!isNull(<columnName>)`  expression as mentioned below:

[image]

Here is the data preview of assert transformation:

[image]

You can configure sink as mentioned below:

Select the sink dataset, got errors in sink select blob linked service and blob file path to store the error values.

[image]

Data preview of sink:

[image]

Error file with null values:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This looks really promising! As we get JSON files  which needs a flatten file activity I placed my assert  after this and chose one of the 6 columns as the !isNull expression. Looks like its working as intended. Only issue is that I dont really want to keep the error files, but if I dont check either "output to sink" or "output to seperate file" it looks like its still giving me a failed pipeline error message?

Comment: If you don't want to store error files, then use filter transformation instead of assert transformation filter null values.